# Performance & Memory Impact In Relation to Assembly Count

Tags: .net, performance, memory, build, assemblies

Our current product is made up of hundreds of projects that result in hundreds of assemblies. We are investigating whether or not it makes sense to modify our build process to build these projects into just a handful of assemblies, and I'm looking for information about what the performance impact would be. Also, a significant amount of memory allocated by our application is made up of assembly images. Would this memory footprint decrease, or stay relatively the same?

Any information you can provide will be much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt we can say that from here. Might be worth adding assembly load event handlers and writing some stats to a log file. You really need to know which are touched, when and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it appears that merging the assemblies should not have an adverse impact on throughput performance, and that it should decrease the working set memory.

Reference:

[Microsoft's Patterns & Practices Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability Chapter 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998530.aspx)